# How to manipulate the 'value' when Setting a property value

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I have the following property in a class:

```
'Language
Private _Language As String = ""
Public Property Language() As String
    Get
        If _Language <> "" Then
            _Language = _Language.Remove(0, 9)
            _Language = _Language.Remove(_Language.Length - 3, 3)
        End If
        Return _Language
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Language = "<![CDATA[" & value & "]]>"
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is that when I try to set the property like this:

```
myClass.Language = "English"
```

The property is set to `"English"` and not to `"<![CDATA[English]]>"` which is what I want.

What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

**Update:**
When placing a break point on End Set and use the Watch window to inspect the value of _Language after setting the property to "English" it remains "English" and doesn't change.

Comment: Did any of these answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the property is actually being set correctly, but the context by which you are viewing the value is hiding the CDATA portion.

Please place a break point on `End Set` and use your `Watch 1` window to inspect the value of _Language after setting the property to English.

Comment: This is exactly what is bugging me. _Language is not set properly. It remains "English" and not "<![CDATA[English]]>".

Answer (score 0):

Your getter is wrong.  It's modifying the property value!  Change the setter value to something else is not recommended because then a Set/Get/Set will not work.

Basically you design is not great.  I would reconsider this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned in a previous comment. The property is designed that way for a reason. I want to use the private value _Langauge in internal class methods.